# How to exclude rows containing null values within columns?

Tags: oracle, case

This is probably not the ideal query to retrieve rows containing specified values within a column, but the solution below effectively returns the values specified in a new column-alias but includes NULL values.  How would the below query be constructed to exclude rows containing NULL values within the column alias?

```
SELECT student_id,
       salutation,
       CASE
           WHEN salutation IN('Dr.') THEN 'Doctor'
       END AS "NewSalutation"
FROM student.student
```

I welcome alternative approaches-thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT student_id,
       salutation,
       CASE
           WHEN salutation IN('Dr.') THEN 'Doctor'
       END AS NewSalutation
FROM student.student
) 
WHERE NewSalutation IS NOT NULL;
```

If that's your only section in the `CASE` statement, a logically equivalent query would be:

```
SELECT student_id,
       salutation,
       CASE
           WHEN salutation IN('Dr.') THEN 'Doctor'
       END AS NewSalutation
FROM student.student
WHERE salutation = 'Dr.';
```

... as anything other than `Dr.` will produce a `NULL` `NewSalutation`.